# Powershell access denied when adding -wait

Tags: powershell

```
Start-Process -Filepath $Target -Credential $cred -ArgumentList '/silent' ,'/forceinstall'
```

Whenever I add -wait at the end of this Start-Process I get an access denied. I want my powershell to wait until the process has stopped before sending me an message. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I think `-ArgumentList '/silent' ,'/forceinstall'` should come directly after `-Filepath $Target`

Comment: Changing that doesn't make a difference. Once I've added the -wait I get access denied.